# Domain Not working properly in search view

Tags: python, odoo

In Opportunity I have 2 categories of user horizontal and vertical.When a vertical user logs in ,his/her name appears in vertical field,but when a hortizontal user logs in his/her name also appears in vertical user field instead of horizontal user field.I have applied domain in search view as below-

for Horizontal user:

```
<field name="user_id" string ="Salesman Horizontal" domain = "
    [('tri_salesteam.s_horizontal','=',True),'|','|','|','|','|','|','|','|',
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id','=',uid),('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),('parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('id','in',[uid])]" invisible="1">
```

for Vertical user:

```
<field name="sales_vertical" domain = "
    [('tri_salesteam.s_horizontal','!=',True),'|','|','|','|','|','|','|','|',
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id','=',uid),('parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),
    ('parent_id.parent_id.parent_id','=',uid),('id','in',[uid])]" invisible="1">
```

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what a horizontal user is and what a vertical user is. Is this something you've written, or part of an official module?

Comment: The users are differentiated as horizontal and vertical depending upon their salesteam selected while creating a user.If Salesteam selected is of type Horizontal ,then that user is horizontal user and rest users are vertical users.

Comment: I think you'll get much better answers if you can describe more about what you want to happen and what is happening. A screenshot of the current behaviour would also be helpful. For example, when you say, "his/her name also appears in vertical user field", do you mean that it appears in the form field, or that it appears in the search box for that field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you're asking, but here's a hint for debugging search conditions. Put a breakpoint or a debug statement in the server code's `orm._search()` method. In version 6.0.3, it's on line 4029 of `server/bin/osv/orm.py` and looks like this:

```
    cr.execute('SELECT "%s".id FROM ' % self._table + from_clause + where_str + order_by + limit_str + offset_str, where_clause_params)
```

If you dump the contents of `where_str`, then you can see how your constraints are being interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use 'parent_of' and 'child_of' in domain instead of using this much '|' conditions for searching the parent_id.